# MQL5 Vline creation

Tags: mql5

I am trying to draw a vertical line on MQL5 Ontick event. But its not printing the line.

Anyone knows what the issue in my code?

```
void OnTick()
  {
  MqlDateTime mqlDateTime;
   TimeToStruct(TimeCurrent(), mqlDateTime);

   // Check if it's 10:00 AM and the line hasn't been drawn yet
   if(mqlDateTime.hour == 10 && mqlDateTime.min == 0 && !ObjectFind(0, "Line_10AM"))
     {
      // Create a vertical line at the current time
      datetime targetTime = TimeCurrent();
      if(!ObjectCreate(0, "Line_10AM", OBJ_VLINE, 0, targetTime, 0))
        {
         Print("Failed to create line: ", GetLastError());
         return;
        }

      // Set the color and style of the line
      ObjectSetInteger(0, "Line_10AM", OBJPROP_COLOR, clrBlue);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, "Line_10AM", OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, "Line_10AM", OBJPROP_WIDTH, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with the code as shown is the `ObjectFind` Function. The return value for `ObjectFind` is the number of the subwindow (0 means the main window of the chart), in which the object is found. If the object is not found, the function returns a negative number.

To correct your code, it should read

```
   MqlDateTime mqlDateTime;
   TimeToStruct(TimeCurrent(), mqlDateTime);

   Comment(mqlDateTime.hour,"\r\n",mqlDateTime.min);

   // Check if it's 10:00 AM and the line hasn't been drawn yet
   if(mqlDateTime.hour == 10 && mqlDateTime.min == 00 && ObjectFind(0, "Line_10AM")<0)
   {
      // Create a vertical line at the current time
      datetime targetTime = TimeCurrent();
      if(!ObjectCreate(0, "Line_10AM", OBJ_VLINE, 0, targetTime, 0))
      {
         Print("Failed to create line: ", GetLastError());
         return;
      }

      // Set the color and style of the line
      ObjectSetInteger(0, "Line_10AM", OBJPROP_COLOR, clrBlue);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, "Line_10AM", OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, "Line_10AM", OBJPROP_WIDTH, 2);
   }
```